# how to supply a common jar in jboss eap 6?

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

How could I make a common jar availabe in jboss 6.4 redhat ?
Is it possible to put it in JBOSS_HOME/standalone/lib ?

01:00:42,659 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Adding dependency ModuleDependency [identifier=LogManager4JBoss-4.1.0rc2.jar:main, moduleLoader=local module loader @16f65612 (finder: local module finder @311d617d (roots: /opt/jboss6/modules,/opt/jboss6/modules/system/layers/base)), export=false, optional=false, importServices=false] to module deployment.tserver-5.0.0.jar:main

01:00:42,670 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-2) Locally loading module LogManager4JBoss-4.1.0rc2.jar:main from local module loader @16f65612 (finder: local module finder @311d617d (roots: /opt/jboss6/modules,/opt/jboss6/modules/system/layers/base))

01:00:42,671 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-2) Module LogManager4JBoss-4.1.0rc2.jar:main **not found** from local module loader @16f65612 (finder: local module finder @311d617d (roots: /opt/jboss6/modules,/opt/jboss6/modules/system/layers/base))

tserver-5.0.0.jar needs some common log stuff from LogManager4JBoss-4.1.0rc2.jar, all the documentation I read so far is confusing, I can't figure out where to put the common jar, this is working in a jboss 4.2.3, I need to use hibernate 3.5 for oracle db synonym support, from jboss 6

Comment: Maybe you should state what you are trying to achieve and what issue you are encountering.

Comment: how to supply a "global" jar in jboss 6 is the issue

Comment: you can add it to a module and define it as a global module so that it will be available to all your deployments. Don't forget to add its dependencies since classloaders aren't flat

Comment: where should the jar go physically ? in what folder ?

Comment: You need to define it in /opt/jboss6/modules/system/layers/base/com/mycompany/mymodule/main with a module.xml. Yo should lookk at the documentation on jboss-modules

Comment: the error seems now gone : in the main jar in META-INF\MANIFEST.MF Dependencies: it.company.logger.implementation then in /opt/jboss6/modules/it/company/logger/implementation/main the dependency jar and module.xml (so, notice, not in /modules/system)

Comment: I have another jar of compass lucene 2.2 of 2009 which isn't found , see : https://github.com/guaxinim/compass/issues/1

Comment: If you need compass.jar as a dependcy in tserver then you might want to add it there or create a new module an reference it from the ts module.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper lucene, 3.6 seems included in jboss 6 /opt/jboss6/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/lucene/main it seems invoked by (system) hibernate
and also junit.framework.TestCase ?

Comment: Having jars you depend on in a module doesn't make it available inthe current module this is NOT a flat classpath, each module has its own classloader so you have to define it properly. Please read jboss module documentation for this.

Comment: Hmm in manifest.mf I put Dependencies: it.company.logger.implementation, org.compass.core, org.springframework.spring, org.apache.lucene.analysis and it seems to not make exception any more for org.apache.lucene.analysis, thank you for any suggestions that I don't understand anything of jboss, already made legacy jboss 4 very complicated application !